# Browser to see LinkedIn pages without login

Tags: firefox, linkedin-api

I use `Firefox` latest version.

When I type a name or a company in google search I take results from LinkedIn

The problem I have is that when I try to click the link to see the content of i.e. company page in linkedin it always redirects me and ask to login.

I tried to make the same process also with `Chrome` and `IE` but again the same results.

Could it be a problem with the browsers?

Comment: It's not browser-specific.